# A formal proof of the monotoncity property of Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have formalized meta-theories for first-order logic with the Coq Proof Assistant.
I defined rule (${\forall}$I) by:
$$ \frac
{\Gamma \vdash \left[ y / x \right] A}
{\Gamma \vdash \left( \forall x \right) A}
$$
provided by
$y \notin \mathrm{FV} \left( \Gamma \right)$ and
$y \notin \mathrm{FV} \left( \left( \forall x \right) A \right)$;
where $x$ is an individual variables and so is $y$, $A$ is a well-formed formula, $\Gamma$ is a set of well-formed formulae, $\mathrm{FV} \left( X \right)$ denotes the set of all free variables occur in object $X$, and $[t/x]\varphi$ is substitution of $t$ for $x$ in $\varphi$.

And then, I have tried to find a formal proof of the monotonicity property, i.e.,
$$ \Gamma \vdash C \, \mathrm{and} \, \Gamma \subseteq \Gamma^{\prime} \implies \Gamma^{\prime} \vdash C . $$
However, if $\Gamma^{\prime}$ is of a set but not a list, it is failed for me to find an individual variable $y^{\prime}$ such that $y^{\prime} \notin \mathrm{FV} \left( \Gamma^{\prime} \right)$ and $y^{\prime} \notin \mathrm{FV} \left( \left( \forall x \right) A \right)$, because $\mathrm{FV} \left( \Gamma \right) \subseteq \mathrm{FV} \left( \Gamma^{\prime} \right)$ .

Actually, letting $v_i$ denote the $i$-th individual variable, there is a counter example:
$$ \emptyset \vdash \left( \forall v_1 \right) \left( v_1 = v_1 \right) \;\not\!\!\!\implies \Gamma \vdash \left( \forall v_1 \right) \left( v_1 = v_1 \right) $$
where $\Gamma := \left\{ v_i = v_i \, | \, i \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$.

So, I am considering a plan: when proving a meta-theory of first-order logic, I add the constraint on $\Gamma$ in the statement of the meta-theory, for which has countably infinite free-variables and is denoted by $\mathbf{P} \left( \cdot \right)$.
If it is accetable, for an example, the statement of the monotonicity property will be
$$ \Gamma \vdash C \, \mathrm{and} \, \Gamma \subseteq \Gamma^{\prime} \, \mathrm{and} \, \mathbf{P} \left( \Gamma^{\prime} \right) \implies \Gamma^{\prime} \vdash C . $$

However, I have not found any textbook in which such a constraint is defined or used. I have two questions:

1. I wonder if the above statement is considered okay in terms of many mathematicians.
2. Furthermore, my question is whether the plan is acceptable or not.

---

On Oct 9, 2023, the original question was:

Title: How can I prove the Monotonicity property of Natural Deduction?

I'm working on making another framework for 1st-order Logic in The Coq Proof Assistant.

I stated $\dot{\forall}$-intro rule:
for any set of formula $\Gamma$ and any formula $C$ and any individual variable $x$ and $y$,
if $\Gamma \vdash C \left[ y / x \right]$
then $\Gamma \vdash \dot{\forall} x , C$
provided by $y \notin \mathrm{FV}\left(\Gamma\right)$
and $y \notin \mathrm{FV} \left(\dot{\forall} x , C \right)$,
where $\varphi \left[ t / x \right]$ denotes the result substituting $x$ for $t$ in $\varphi$.

To prove the Monotonicity property, I struggled with the condition $y \notin \mathrm{FV} \left( \Gamma \right)$.
Assume $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$ and $\Gamma \vdash C$.
Then, to prove $\Delta \vdash C$,
it is required to [assume](https://github.com/KiJeong-Lim/neoDschingisKhan/blob/6b146c1840894c4b42ec0a7e4414190f062f8626/theories/System/Fol2.v#L183) $\mathrm{FV} \left( \Gamma \right) = \mathrm{FV} \left( \Delta \right)$.

So I wonder that the $\dot{\forall}$-intro rule is correct.
If so, how can I prove the property?

Or, how can I state again correctly if it is wrong?
Since I've already proved the soundness theorem of Natural Deduction for the Tarski's semantics,
I hope it correct.

---

Proving the following Extraction Lemma requires the Monotonicity property:
[image: Extraction Lemma]
where p⟦ x ↦ t ⟧ denotes $p \left[ t / x \right]$.

Comment: IMO the issue is a little bit tricky... Usually monotonicity is proved (easily) ate the semantic level using truth valuations. At the syntactic level, we can say that it is built-in into ND rules, because we are not forced to use all assumptions and thus we can "assume" that a new unused assumption does not change the status of the derivation. If you want a proof, I think it must be a formalization by induction of the previous argument.

Comment: But... we have to take care of $(\forall \text I)$ rule with its proviso. In principle, if we have a correct derivation $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$, adding to $\Gamma$ a formula with $x$ free may "destroy" the correctness. In the end, we are able to generalize on $x$ because the assumptions in $\Gamma$ do not say nothing about $x$, and thus $x$ can refer to an object whatever. If we add a new "axiom" (this is a new assumption) involving $x$, it is nor more true that $x$ can refer to an object whatever.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So do you mean that, given any derivation $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, one can extract the used assumption $\Gamma^{\prime}$ from $\Gamma$?
But proving this extraction lemma requires the monotonicity property.

Comment: Yes and no... But every rule that discharge an assumption (like e.g. to-Intro) will have a specific occurrence of an assumption. Listing them you have the list of effective assumption tracked. But what I mean is that the to-Intro rule is $\dfrac {\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \psi}{\Gamma \vdash \varphi \to \psi}$. There is nothing limiting $\Gamma$ and thus we may simply assert that every ND rule discharging assumption has Monotonicity built-in. This is the basis for induction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But adding a new assumption to $\Gamma$ could make the $\left(\forall I\right)$ rule no longer applied. And I uploaded a figure which explains why the monotonicity property is required to prove the extraction lemma.

Comment: For monotonicity, the trick will be: change the variable $x$ with a new variable $z$ and then add the extra-assumptions involving $x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA 1. It is NOT always possible to find a variable $z$ such that $z \notin \mathrm{FV} \left( \Gamma \right)$ because $\Gamma$ may not be finite. 2. And I can't guess what the extra-assumptions are. That is, what are the statements of them?